# Cursor de rango de fechas, separando la fecha y la hora

Tags: sql, oracle

¿Cómo separar la fecha y la hora de este campo **sms.fecha_registro**? Por defecto es un `sysdate`; se requiere que cuando haga la consulta aparezcan 2 campos, uno con la fecha y otro con la hora.

```
 CURSOR c_datos(ln_idregistro in number) is  
  SELECT cl.nrodocumento,sms.fecha_registro,sms.mensaje_envio,sms.estado_envio, sms.numero_celular
    FROM cl_relperdoc cl , dm_trx_envio_sms sms
  WHERE cl.IDPERSONA = sms.id_registro 
     AND sms.fecha_registro BETWEEN To_date(rp_fecha_desde) 
     AND To_date(rp_fecha_hasta)
     OR cl.nrodocumento = rp_cedula ;
```

Answer (score 0):

### ¡UPDATED! Actualizo con el comentario de Sal, porque mi respuesta es para SQL Server y la pregunta es para Oracle. La dejo por si le es útil a alguien que le suceda lo mismo en SQL Server (o la borro si los administradores piensan es mejor borrarla), pero no sé si es válida o no para Oracle (me imagino que no).

Lo puedes hacer con un convert a los tipos `date` o `time`. Este ejemplo creo que te será de utilidad:

```
create table MiTabla (
  fecha date,
  hora time
)
declare @fechaHora as datetime = getdate()
insert into MiTabla select convert(date, @fechaHora), convert(time, @fechaHora)

select * from MiTabla
```

Lo que hacemos es separar la hora de la fecha y mostrarla. Y devolvería lo siguiente:

| fecha | hora |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-16 | 09:36:08.5300000 |

Para tu ejemplo en particular, lo primero que deberías hacer es no usar cursores. Nunca, o prácticamente nunca, son necesarios y tienen una eficiencia horrible. Pero la select de tu cursor mostraría fecha y hora así:

```
CURSOR c_datos(ln_idregistro in number) is  
SELECT 
    convert(date, cl.nrodocumento,sms.fecha_registro) fecha_registro,
    convert(time, cl.nrodocumento,sms.fecha_registro) hora_registro,
    sms.mensaje_envio,sms.estado_envio, sms.numero_celular
    FROM cl_relperdoc cl , dm_trx_envio_sms sms
  WHERE cl.IDPERSONA = sms.id_registro 
     AND sms.fecha_registro BETWEEN To_date(rp_fecha_desde) 
     AND To_date(rp_fecha_hasta)
     OR cl.nrodocumento = rp_cedula ;
```

No lo he probado porque no has proporcionado datos de ejemplo, solo he modificado sobre tu propia select.

Comment: Sugiero que hagas click en las etiquetas de la pregunta.

Comment: @Sal Tienes toda la razón del mundo. Perdón. No sé si se ha puesto la etiqueta después de responder yo o si es que no me he fijado.